Solution of equation with unknown under the integral
I have a problem which I have reduced to solving the following equation for the unknown $r_0$:
$$
1/2 = \int_0^D f(r)p(r,r_0)dr
$$
where $D \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is continuous density function.
$p(r,r_0)$ can be any function which I am looking to impose some restrictions on to make the equation solvable.
I am sure that the solution exists for $p(r, r_0) = \exp\left(-\frac{r}{r_0}\right)$ by plotting the integral over $r_0$ and using numerical methods, but I would like to find an analytic solution to use later on.
My issue is that $f(r)$ is not a very 'nice' function, and so I can't solve the equation by directly integrating.
I've tried looking at integral equations, such as Volterra and Fredholm equations, but I think these are looking to find the function $f$ in my example, which I already know.
Is there a different method that I'm missing to find the unknown in this sort of equation, other than just integrating it directly?

Exactly what do you want to find here ? $p$ ? $r$ ? $f$ ?

@Prem I'm looking to find $r_0$ which is a real number greater than $0$.

What things are known/fixed ? What things can we select ?

$f(r)$ is a fixed probability density function, $D$ is a fixed real number. For context my original problem is that I've conjectured something is true for any $p$ which is monotonic decreasing in $r_0$, and $p$ is bounded between 0 and 1. Basically I'm looking for a general method to solve equations of the above type for the unknown $r_0$, but I don't know what restrictions I need to put on the function $p$ in order to do so. Maybe it's better to frame the question as solve $1/2=\mathbb{E}[p(R,r_0)]$ where $R$ has density $f$, but I'm not sure.
